# Detecting bad URLs

Tags: node.js, regex, url

I have an API that sometimes return a value like this `http://www.trinidadexpress.comhttp://www.trinidadexpress.com/storyimage/TT/20171220/LOCAL/171229994/AR/0/AR-171229994.jpg&MaxW=400`

Is there a way using `node.js` to detect a URL like this (basically having 2 http:// within the url) and if it has this pattern replace it will a URL such as `https://www.wefornews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/news-3.jpg`

Comment: Fix the API or use a different one, that isn't normal. Tackle the source, don't apply a bandaid and hope it sticks

Comment: "basically having 2 http:// within the url", who needs node.js if in plain Js you can already use a regex or even a plain string search to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to match the string you want to find is very simple: `/https?:\/\//g` (find characters "http", `s?` means one or none of "s", and "://" with the `/` escaped)

To check if a string has multiple instances of it, use `String.prototype.match` and check the length of the returned array.

Here's an example:

```js
var str = "http://www.trinidadexpress.comhttp://www.trinidadexpress.com/storyimage/TT/20171220/LOCAL/171229994/AR/0/AR-171229994.jpg&MaxW=400";
if (str.match(/https?:\/\//g).length > 1) {
    alert("invalid url!");
}
```